# Ruby on Rails: Routing for a tree hierarchy of places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, hierarchy, hierarchical-trees

So we've got a legacy system that tracks places with IDs like "Europe/France/Paris", and I'm building a Rails facade to turn this into URLs like http:// foobar/places/Europe/France/Paris.  This requirement is not negotiable, the number of possible levels in unlimited, and we can't escape the slashes.

Setting up routes.rb for http://foobar/places/Europe is trivial:

```
map.resources :places
```

...but http:// foobar/places/Europe/France complains "No action responded to Europe".  I tried:

```
map.connect '/places/:id', :controller => 'places', :action => 'show'
```

...but this gives the same result, as apparently the :id ends at the first '/'.  How do I make the ID cover anything and everything after the "places"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the Routing Guide for full documentation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Specifically section "4.9 Route Globbing".

But I think what you really want to do is declare your route like:

```
map.connect '/places/*id', :controller => 'places', :action => 'index'
```

Called with a URL like

```
/places/foo/bar/1

Yields a params[:id] => ["foo", "bar", "1"]
```

Which you could easily (re)join with "/" to yield the full string you want "foo/bar/1" (you will probably have to re-insert the leading slash manually.

That should get you going.

Comment: Brilliant, that almost works!  The only problem is that the content is now always rendered as HTML, even if I try to force it with a ".xml" suffix?  I'm using the standard respond_to do |format| block.

Comment: It looks like route globbing with :format support is a known issue - that is, it doesnt work, as you found out. The bug / patch is here discussed here: http://bit.ly/5LICLH   but it looks like its not in the current release of Rails. Since you have no control of the URL portion (the route) the best I can think of is adding a query string parameter (?format=xml or ?format=json) which you can detect in your controller and act accordingly. Otherwise, it looks like you're SOL

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked Cody's answer above slightly to come up with this:

```
map.place '/places/*id', :controller => 'places', :action => 'show'
map.connect '/places/*id.:format', :controller => 'places', :action => 'show'
```

By using map.place instead of map.connect, Rails knows what resource we're dealing with and generated `place_url`, `place_path` etc helpers correctly.

Now, the 2nd line *should* work but doesn't thanks to the bug above, so here's a workaround for places_controller.rb that manually splits the ID and sets the format, defaulting to XML:

```
id, suffix = params[:id].join('/').split('.') 
params[:format] = suffix ? suffix : "xml"
```

Comment: Nice touch on just grabbing the format from the last path component. That should do the trick!

Comment: It dawned on me a bit later that the id may also contain dots, so using .split(/\.(html|xml)$/) is a bit safer.